# Pouring two types of fluid

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation

I am getting to get familiar with blender and there is a huge question regarding fluid simulation.
In a short animation I'd like to combine two different liquids, one which is already in a "cup" with the other one which comes from a point - as you can see it on the pictures below.
The problem is that i cannot make the yellow solid into fluid that interacts with the blue liquid and that they also combining their colours and quantity.
Do you have any idea how i can manage to get it done?

Thank you very much in for your help, in advance! :)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is not a problem to mix one liquid with another, but there is not a way to combine two colours or liquid density (like water-oil) with current manta flow solver. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MLwCFOsgYrI) it is faked by two sims that doesn't interact and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2KvuDgRMS4) is a nice result with Particles, but that is not what you want, but could be interesting to test it to light meshed fluid result by those particles :)

Comment: Hi, vklidu!
Thank you very much for the answer and the help! :)
I've been thinking of achiving the result i want with the help of the first video that you linked to me. I think that is going to get me the closest. The other video seems interesting as well. :)
May i have a tiny question as well?
Is there a way that i can make the "yellow" object a calm liquid? Because every time i try to make that fluid, even if it being:
Fluid
Type: Liquid
Flow type: Liquid
Flow Behavior: Geometry

It is kinda bubbling and it is not a simple calm "water" fluid.
Thank you very much in advance! :)

Comment: Probably better if you share your file, to let us check. (Yelow liquid is not reacting, because was not set as liquid at all, but you already noticed that.) If you don't care about colours make it as a one sim so they react together (or you cal fake color mix by shader setup). Or could be interesting try sim failing one first and when liquid mesh is generated use it as obstacle and sim yellow one :)

Comment: Hello there! :)
Thank you very much for taking your time on this topic. 
Yes, i think i should share the file so you can have a look at it.. :)
Here you can find the original file i was asking about:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-tKn56CV9Uq0f1qQqOZNJOQYISwwpnVr/view?usp=sharing
Thank you very much again! :)

Comment: If no one I will check it tomorrow, btw you didn't give permission for download ... for now check my answer if you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

In mean time I recreated one ...

[image]
[image]

[image]

Faked color mix ...

[image]

Comment: Hi, vklidu!
Thank you very much for the blender file.
The sharing should have worked i don't know what happened.
I've been trying yesterday and now i have donloaded your file and i've gotten to find the same solution that you made in the shared file. :)
The colour changing with the fake colour mix is a great idea! :)
Thank you very much for taking your time on trying to help me with this one! :) 
I'm gonna show you my final render when it's done just for fun! :)
Thank you again, have a lovely day, mate! :)